# Vue - Rewrite a computed property inside parent - Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a parent child communication, on the parent I'm receiving the emitted data from the child  [Proxy].
On the parent I'm using the `filteredReceipes` (computed property) in a v-for for showing the final data.
What I would like to achieve is "rewrite" the filteredReceipes computed property, the line before the console.log. I have more children that will change that filteredReceipes. Actually it shows me `'filteredRecipes' is constant`.

```
// parent
<template>
  <childComponent @emitSearch="filterText" />
  <div v-for="(item, index) in filteredReceipes" :key="index">
    ------
  </div>

</template>
<script>
  ----
  setup() {
    const {
      state,
      favoritesReceipes,
      -------
      filteredRecipes
    } = wState();

    const filterText = e => {
      filteredRecipes = e;
      console.log("Filter text", e);
    };
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      ----
      filteredReceipes,
      filterText
    };
```

My Child Component

```
<template>
  <input="searchTyped" />
</template>
<script>
-----
emits: ["emitSearch"],

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const { state, filteredRecipes } = wState();

    const searchTyped = () => {
      emit("emitSearch", state.filteredRecipes);
    };
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      filteredRecipes,
      searchTyped
    };
  }
```

recipes.js

```
export const wState = () => {
    const filteredRecipes = computed(() => {
        let tempRecipes = state.recipes;
        ---
        return tempRecipes;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have specified everything as `const` so they are constants and won't let you rewrite them

Comment: @beshambherChaukhwan I'f I change in recipes.js the const to let, it shows me the same error message

Comment: Yeah I forgot. You need to use refs to access the child. Add `ref="Child"` in child html `<ChildComponent... ` and before that console.log you need to change that variable by `this.$refs.Child.filteredRecipes=updatedValue` and then you need to check its reactivity for re-rendering

Comment: I need to change the value of filteredrecipes on the Parent where I have the v-for. My Child it's filtering and returning to the parent the correct values. Sorry if I am not understanding you properly.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Then you need to make your `filterText` as a method in Parent i.e., methods: { filterText(e) { this.filteredRecipes=e; } }

Comment: And make `filteredRecipes` in parent as non const variable

Comment: On parent `const filterText = e =>{`   is a method, using compoisition API. `filteredRecipes = e;` is the way to use it without the `this`

Comment: Then it should work. I can't see the problem here the code looks fine.

Comment: I solved. I dont need to pass to the Child filteredRecipes. I just need to send to the parent the typed word and assign it to the v-model on the parent.
Thank you for helping me to think in a better way @Beshambher Chaukhwan

Comment: Oh okay cool. Honestly I couldn't understand the requirements properly but if it ends well it's all well :D